# Grails 2.x createCriteria 'or' doesn't work for nested associations

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, createcriteria

It seems that in Grails 2.x, if you have a domain class association, and you try to run a createCriteria using `or` on that relation + another query, the `or` will ignore the other query and just use the results of the nested association.  I realize this may be a little confusing, so here is an example:

```
class Passenger {
    Long id
    Boolean isDriving
}

class Car {
    Long id
    Passenger passenger
    Boolean isMoving

    static constraints = {
        passenger nullable: true
    }
}
```

and a test:

```
class CarIntegrationTests {
    @Test
    void testCar() {
    Passenger passenger1 = new Passenger(isDriving: true)
    passenger1.save()

    Car car1 = new Car(passenger: passenger1, isMoving: false)
    Car car2 = new Car(isMoving: true)

    car1.save()
    car2.save()

        def queryResults = Car.createCriteria().list() {
            or {
                eq('isMoving', true)// This by itself works

                passenger {// And this by itself works
                    eq('isDriving', true)
                }
            }// But OR'd, it only returns the results of the nested part
        }

        assertEquals 2, queryResults.size() // Returns 1
    }
}
```

This same code worked in older versions of Grails, but doesn't not seem to work now -- does anyone know of a good workaround to this, other than running multiple queries?

Comment: Try turning on hibernate logging and see what sql is being generated.  As a work-around you could just write an hql query, but you shouldn't have to

Comment: @JimSosa Yeah I'll try it with logging.  I was hoping not to use HQL, but yeah, I might have to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Post Grails 2.x, Criteria by default uses `inner` join, but for this particular case `outer` join has to be used as passenger association will not allow to follow `or` condition if it is an `inner` join and passenger is not set to car.

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria

def queryResults = Car.createCriteria().list() {
    createAlias('passenger', 'passenger', Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    or {
        eq('isMoving', true)
        eq('passenger.isDriving', true)
    }
}
```

Comment: @GrailsGuy See my update. Outer join has to be used.

Comment: Note by grails 3/hibernate 4+, Criteria is deprecated and should be JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN instead, but otherwise still a perfect answer.